# Running django project using mod_wsgi on aws

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, mod-wsgi

I have deployed a django project on aws.
i am using apache2 server and mod_wsgi.
After executing the command

```
$ python manage.py runmodwsgi --host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

it gives an output

```
Server URL         : http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/
Server Root        : /tmp/mod_wsgi-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000:1000
Server Conf        : /tmp/mod_wsgi-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000:1000/httpd.conf
Error Log File     : /tmp/mod_wsgi-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000:1000/error_log (warn)
Request Capacity   : 5 (1 process * 5 threads)
Request Timeout    : 60 (seconds)
Queue Backlog      : 100 (connections)
Queue Timeout      : 45 (seconds)
Server Capacity    : 20 (event/worker), 20 (prefork)
Server Backlog     : 500 (connections)
Locale Setting     : en_US.UTF-8
```

But when i try to access http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/ from browser, i get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error.
Can somebody what i may be doing wrong.

Note : Access log is empty

Comment: And if you don't provide the ``--host`` argument but still use the IP address in the URL? So long as you don't define ``--host`` it should listen on all interfaces anyway. In that case you just need to use the correct public URL. Doesn't it have a proper hostname rather than an IP address?